# How to increase efficiency of a query with two CONNECT BY LEVEL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've made pretty inefficient 1.5 billion cost query:
[image]

This query is going to be used when making excel reports. It dublicates rows according to columns value. Later I will join other tables to this query. And that will increase the cost even more.
[image]

I have to mention that cost decreases down to 153m without order by.

What am I doing wrong? Why the cost is so big?

```
SELECT ID,
       CLINIC,
       ADDRESS,
       TRIM(regexp_substr(RISKS, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value)) AS risk,
       TRIM(regexp_substr(ages, '[^,]+', 1, levels2.column_value)) AS age
FROM   (SELECT id, clinic, address, risks,
               CASE
                  WHEN ladult = 'Y' AND lchild = 'Y' THEN
                   'kids, adults'
                  WHEN ladult = 'N' AND lchild = 'N' THEN
                   NULL
                  ELSE
                   CASE
                      WHEN ladult = 'Y' AND lchild = 'N' THEN
                       'kids'
                      ELSE
                       'adults'
                   END
               END AS ages
        FROM   med.clinics
        WHERE  tender = 1111111),
       TABLE(CAST(MULTISET (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(risks, ',') + 1) AS
                  sys.OdciNumberList)) LEVELS,
       TABLE(CAST(MULTISET (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(ages, ',') + 1) AS sys.OdciNumberList)) LEVELS2
ORDER  BY clinic
```

Comment: You have a bug in your code when `ladult = 'Y' and lchild = 'N'` then you set the value to `kids` and not `adults`.

Comment: Half way down this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=49938cbd91b4d68e672f071cf45cbfe9) is a version of your hierarchical query that does not use regular expressions and uses `UNPIVOT` on the ages; however Oracle still puts the cost an order of magnitude greater than using a recursive sub-query factoring clause so I'm only posting it here for interest rather than as a solution.

Comment: @MT0 you are right, I made a mistake there. I know that thank you comments are not appreciated here, but I must say that you've done an outstandig work here. Your solution and comments are very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause and simple string functions (rather than slow regular expressions) to split the delimited strings and can use `UNPIVOT` to transpose the `Kids` and `Adults` columns to rows:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE med_check_lpu_details ( id, clinic, address, risks, kids, adults ) As
  SELECT 1, 'City Hospital', 'City, Street 1', 'ambulance,dentistry', 'Y', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Pain Factory',  'City, Street 8', 'ambulatory',          'N', 'Y' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH risk_substr_bounds ( id, clinic, address, risks, kids, adults, startidx, endidx ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         clinic,
         address,
         risks,
         CASE kids   WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Kids'   END AS kids,
         CASE adults WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Adults' END AS adults,
         1,
         INSTR( risks, ',', 1 )
  FROM   med_check_lpu_details
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         clinic,
         address,
         risks,
         kids,
         adults,
         endidx + 1,
         INSTR( risks, ',', endidx + 1 )
  FROM   risk_substr_bounds
  WHERE  endidx > 0
)
SELECT id,
       clinic,
       address,
       CASE
       WHEN endidx = 0
       THEN SUBSTR( risks, startidx )
       ELSE SUBSTR( risks, startidx, endidx - startidx )
       END AS risk,
       age
FROM   risk_substr_bounds
UNPIVOT( age FOR key IN ( kids, adults ) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | CLINIC        | ADDRESS        | RISK       | AGE   
> -: | :------------ | :------------- | :--------- | :-----
>  1 | City Hospital | City, Street 1 | ambulance  | Kids  
>  1 | City Hospital | City, Street 1 | ambulance  | Adults
>  2 | Pain Factory  | City, Street 8 | ambulatory | Adults
>  1 | City Hospital | City, Street 1 | dentistry  | Kids  
>  1 | City Hospital | City, Street 1 | dentistry  | Adults
> ```

**Explain Plan**:

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                         |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | Plan hash value: 2835086753                                                                                               |
> |                                                                                                                           |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation                                  | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                           |                            |     8 |   632 |    10  (30)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION                 |                            |       |       |            |          | |
> | |   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT                           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D67B9_3195F48 |       |       |            |          | |
> | |   3 |    UNION ALL (RECURSIVE WITH) BREADTH FIRST|                            |       |       |            |          | |
> | |   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                      | MED_CHECK_LPU_DETAILS      |     2 |   108 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  5 |     RECURSIVE WITH PUMP                    |                            |       |       |            |          | |
> | |*  6 |   VIEW                                     |                            |     8 |   632 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   7 |    UNPIVOT                                 |                            |       |       |            |          | |
> | |   8 |     VIEW                                   |                            |     4 |   352 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   9 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D67B9_3195F48 |     4 |   352 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                                                           |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                       |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                                                       |
> |                                                                                                                           |
> |    5 - filter("ENDIDX">0)                                                                                                 |
> |    6 - filter("unpivot_view_009"."AGE" IS NOT NULL)                                                                       |
> |                                                                                                                           |
> | Note                                                                                                                      |
> | -----                                                                                                                     |
> |    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)                                                                   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cfffe557c9a7c292931c8212d94cd6bb)*

---

> What am I doing wrong?

Don't use delimited strings if you can help it; you could have a separate table for the risks with one row per risk per id and use a `JOIN` to include it in the query rather than having to split the delimited string every time.

For example:

```sql
-- Primary Key on ( id )
CREATE TABLE med_check_lpu_details ( id, clinic, address, kids, adults ) As
  SELECT 1, 'City Hospital', 'City, Street 1', 'Y', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Pain Factory',  'City, Street 8', 'N', 'Y' FROM DUAL;

-- Foreign key on id => med_check_lpu_details.id
-- Primary key on ( id, risk )
CREATE TABLE med_check_lpu_details_risks ( id, risk ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'ambulance'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'dentistry'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'ambulatory' FROM DUAL;
```

Similarly, for `Kids` and `Adults`, you have then in separate columns and you are concatenating them into a delimited string and then splitting that string; that is a lot of work. Instead, just `UNPIVOT` the columns you have as its much cheaper.